# Non-Copyable Within Class

Tags: c++, sockets, pointers, stl, sfml

I've been working on a server written in C++ and using SFML networking for the sockets and all. However, I've ran into a bit of a dead end for me. SFML Sockets are non-copyable and thus cannot be stored into most(all the ones that I know of) stl containers.

So, I quickly jumped to the idea of using a pointer and then it hit me that I should use RAII, but I hate smart pointers and needed to store more information than just the pointer to the Socket class.

I wrote a Client class that wraps the socket and deletes it when the destructor on the Client class gets called, which is fine and dandy..until I remembered that the stl containers will copy my class, delete the pointer and then I'd be left with a dangling pointer.

So, is there anyway I can get around non-copyables? I need the pointer to be stored within the class and I need the class to destroy the allocated memory.

I figured I could use a copy constructor to set the copied classes' pointer to null, but I cannot find a way to do that.

For Reference:

`Client.cpp`

```
Client::Client()
{
}; 

Client::Client(sf::TcpSocket* in_Connection)
{
    m_Connection = in_Connection; 
    m_IPAddress = m_Connection->getRemoteAddress().toString();
    m_AccountName = "NOACCOUNT";
    m_CharacterName = "NOCHARACTER";
};

Client::~Client()
{

    m_Connection->disconnect();
    delete m_Connection; 
};

//getters
sf::TcpSocket* Client::getConnection()
{
    return m_Connection;
};

std::string Client::getIPAddress()
{
    return m_IPAddress;
};

std::string Client::getAccountName()
{
    return m_AccountName;
};

std::string Client::getCharacterName()
{
    return m_CharacterName;
};

//setters -- Account Name and Character Name are the only two that can be changed during a connection.
void Client::setAccountName(std::string in_AccountName)
{
    m_AccountName = in_AccountName;
};

void Client::setCharacterName(std::string in_CharacterName)
{
    m_CharacterName = in_CharacterName; 
};

//Copy Constructor <--This defintely won't work and I know that, haha.
Client::Client(const Client& that)
{
    m_Connection = new sf::TcpSocket();
    *m_Connection = *that.m_Connection; // Cannot copy non-copyable 
    m_IPAddress = that.m_IPAddress;
    m_CharacterName = that.m_CharacterName;
    m_AccountName = that.m_AccountName; 
};
```

**Server Accept Function**

```
void Server::AcceptConnections()
{
    sf::TcpSocket* Socket = new sf::TcpSocket(); 

    if( m_Listener.accept(*Socket) == sf::Socket::Done)
    {   
        if(Socket != NULL )
        {
            std::string IPAddress = Socket->getRemoteAddress().toString();

            if( m_Connections.find( IPAddress ) == m_Connections.end() )
            {
                std::cout  << IPAddress;
                std::cout << " Has Connected.";
                std::endl( std::cout );

                m_Connections.insert( std::make_pair(IPAddress, Client(Socket) ) ); 
            }
        }
    }
};
```

Comment: 'I should use RAII, but I hate smart pointers' - seems you're somewhat conflicted then.

Comment: Aren't we all from time to time? :P

Comment: Use a smart pointer. This is exactly why they exist.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, whether you can use C++11 or not is a game changer.

In C++11, you have the concept of *move*. Unlike copying, moving is not about duplicating but about transferring. All Standard containers were adapted to non-copyable classes that are movable.

An example of a movable class:

```
class Client {
public:
    Client(Client const&) = delete; // non copyable
    Client& operator=(Client const&) = delete; // non copy assignable

    Client(Client&&) = default; // movable
    Client& operator=(Client&&) = default; // move assignable

private:
    std::unique_ptr<sf::TcpSocket> _socket;
};
```

And your problem is solved.

---

If you are stuck in C++03 land, you are in for a bit of trouble. The simplest solution would be to use a manager class:

- the manager owns the instance
- users of the instance only ever manipulates references/pointers to it

Comment: Thanks, I'm having a bit of trouble implementing the move semantics, but I'll have it here soon.

Comment: @user2807377: if you use a `unique_ptr` and rely on `= default` you don't have anything to implement, really.

Comment: Unfortunately MSVC++ 2012 doesn't seem to implement default and delete like they are defined in your code, so I made the copy and copy-assignment operator private and then implemented the move and move assignment operator and it works flawlessly.

Comment: @ZacWade: ah, you're unlucky to have to work with MSVC 2012 :( Glad you managed to solve your issue though!